# Silk Test Open Agent doesn't stop automatically after tests execution

Tags: java, jenkins, silktest

I have an issue with Silk Test's Open Agent (Silk Test 2011).

I am using Silk4J for acceptance tests written in Java for a C++ client. It starts the tests properly but does not stop after the tests are completed. I have to do it manually so the job is completed in Jenkins.

Silk Test 2011 with Hotfix3 is installed on my Windows 7 SP1 (64bit). 
The Silk Test 2011 release notes mention turning off user access control and I have done so.

I am having a hard time isolating the problem and hope somebody may have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Silk Test's Open Agent should not be blocking your tests from completion.

In the past I've seen similar issues by the Java VM leaking sockets to their child processes, which then occasionally causes another processes to think the JVM was still alive.

You could try

- Upgrading the involved JVM(s)
- Upgrading Silk Test (2011 is ancient)
- Take a close look at the network sockets the various processes have open, if the first two steps don't solve your issue, this might help you find out why.